# Receiving empty response in outbound gateway prevents execution of further steps in IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring-integration

I have a simple IntegrationFlow sending SOAP messages with MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway. The deal is that, normally, the target service responds with empty message. It can of course return soap fault, but, on success, we expect an empty response. Now the problem is that if we get an empty response, SI recognizes it as "no response" and does not execute steps that are after the gateway in the IntegrationFlow. This happens even if gateway is set with setIgnoreEmptyResponses(false). According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ws/AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.html#setIgnoreEmptyResponses-boolean-), it only works if it received an empty String, but response returned from the service is represented as null in my case.

I want to be able to continue the flow no matter if external service responds with empty or non-empty response. What would be the best way to achieve that?

**EDIT1:** It feels especially odd, because it stops execution of the IntegrationFlow even if both handlers are subscribed to publishSubscribeChannel (instead of being directly on the main flow). I would expect all subscribers to be executed unless the previous one produced an exception, but this is not what happens.

```java
MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway outboundGateway = new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(
            gatewaysUtils.buildOutboundUriToX(webServiceProperties.getServicePath()),
            jaxb2Marshaller, messageFactory);
        outboundGateway.setIgnoreEmptyResponses(false);

IntegrationFlows.from(channelName())
            .transform(getKafkaMarshaller()::deserialize)
            .handle(getOutboundGateway())
            .handle(messageStatusRegistrator.registerMessageStatus())
            .get();
```

**EDIT2:** Having tried the publishSubscribeChannel again, it worked this time around. It feels a bit hacky to me, but apparently it does work without any side-effects (for now). Fixed flow below. One thing to be careful about is scenario, when the service returns a non-empty, non-error response, which can potentially cause "output-channel or replychannel header available" if you do not provide the header or replyChannel explicitly.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(channelName())
            .transform(getKafkaMarshaller()::deserialize)
            .publishSubscribeChannel(channel -> channel
                .subscribe(subflow -> subflow
                    .handle(getOutboundGateway()))
                .subscribe(subflow -> subflow
                    .handle(messageStatusRegistrator::registerMessageStatus)))
            .get();
```

Comment: Returning `null` is designed to terminate the flow; the pub/sub solution should work though; show your configuration for that case.

Comment: It is a bit puzzling, but now I tried pubsub solution again, it suddenly worked this time around. I swear it didn't the last time for some reason and I (probably) didn't have any strange configuration at the time. Thank you for the tip